# Android Studio Unreported exception SQLException & ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android

Hi i'm trying to establish a connection between Android Studio and MS SQL Server 2008 but i really cant and i dont know why.. someone can help me?

```
  String userName = "gav-iis";
   String password = "gstmpvr";
   String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://gav-cptr\\gav\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=GAV_Manutencao";
   Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
   if(!(conn == null)) {
       System.out.println("Conetado");
   }
```

I have 2 errors, 1st:
Error:(25, 21) error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
2nd: Error:(26, 53) error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a basic exception handling problem. You need to surround the lines that may throw an exception a try statement, and catch exceptions that may occur.

```
try{
    // your code
}
catch(Exception e){
    // handle exception
}
```

You can leave the exception handling part blank, but you still have to explicitly have a case if an exception occurs.

Comment: meanwhile i discovered that, but still with SQLException problem

Comment: It's not the same issue? Do you have a try for both lines? Do you have a catch for SQLException?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://gav-cptr/gav\\SQLEXPRESS;";
    String nomeBD = "GAV_Manutencao";
    String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String user = "iestagiario";
    final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, "");
        System.out.println("Conetado " + nomeBD);
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Desconetado");
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " ligado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    catch ( Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```